# Trying to add pagenumbering, but no footer will display

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

All I'm really looking to do is add page numbers to the bottom of each page.  However, whatever method I try doesn't seem to show up.  I've tried searching for this and come up with nothing.  Here's a simple example of what I want to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{%
Text
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Subtitle}

Plain text.

\pagebreak

\subsection{Another subtitle}

More plain text.

\end{document}
```

And it works just great.  However, when I add `\fancyfoot` to my document, nothing shows up.  Yet the `\fancyhead` line works just fine.  I've tried using `\pagenumbering{arabic}` and `\cfoot` as well and they are similarly ignored.  Even going as far as to try to manually add the footer to the content pages doesn't do the job.  Obviously this means that somewhere in my document I'm overriding the footer, but the only commands I'm calling after this in my original document are the following:

```
\tableofcontents
\include
\newcommand
\section
\begin{figure}
```

None of which, as far as I know, should overwrite the footer for the rest of my document.  The following code inserted after my `\begin{document}` does the job, but obviously blows away my previous header.

```
\pagestyle{headings}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

I apologize in advance that this doesn't cleanly point to the problem, but I wasn't sure how to give enough information without pasting in my entire document.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: This statement says it all: "Obviously this means that somewhere in my document I'm [over-writing] the footer" This may very well be the case, but without more of that "somewhere", it's difficult to assess.

Comment: Your `\include` and `\newcommand` as posted are incorrectly used.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) and Thank you for the [MWE code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Yes, I do realize it's difficult to assess, which is why I'm struggling with it.  The only commands I issue following setting the footer are listed in the middle code box, and as far as I know none of them should override it.  Are there any other places I should look?

And while the include and newcommand are incorrectly used as posted, I have used them correctly in my document.  I commented them out to be sure and no change, regardless.

Comment: I don't have any problems with your example.  Can you please post a M(non)WE.  It's otherwise very hard to assess what's going on.

Comment: @LearningLaTeX: `\tableofcontents`, in [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) or [`book`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) sets `\thispagestyle{plain}`, since a header here would "interfere" with the chapter heading. `article` shouldn't do this. What `\documentclass` are you using? Some (like [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) and [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)) might have their own settings for this, and might not enjoy an interaction with [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr).

Comment: I was using \documentclass{article}.

Thanks for the help - the issue was that I was calling \usepackage[top=.8in, bottom=.5in, left=.5in, right=.5in]{geometry} - i.e. my bottom margin was wiping out my footer.